# Nexus filling up disk space on /var/tmp

Tags: nexus

We have a nexus server. The /var/tmp directly fills up the root volume with createrepoXXXXXX directories.

We are using nexus version 2.14.1-01

Is it safe to delete these files?

Should nexus be cleaning up these files?

Is there a way to safely cleanup these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These directories are from the "createrepo" command line tool, which is used by Nexus 2 to generate yum metadata for yum enabled repositories.

Unfortunately it's a known issue that createrepo will not always clean these up.

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6773?focusedCommentId=272658&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-272658

The location of this directory is hard coded in the createrepo python sources, there is no way to override it. It is safe to delete these files.

YUM support in Nexus 3.x does not rely on createrepo and avoids this problem.